# If voltage of x-rays is doubled then intensity of X-rays will be?

Tags: energy, waves, x-rays, quantization

My text book says it will remain unchanged because intensity of x-rays depends upon the current and number of electron. If this is true we can also say, the current depends upon voltage.
So, why we can’t say x-rays depends upon voltage

[image: fig. Coolidge Tube]

Comment: What even is the experimental setup? Voltage of which part? Current of which part?

Comment: I am taking about Coolidge Tube. I have updated the question with figure!.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few objects fail to strictly follow Ohm's law and a prominent example in this regard are heated cathodes.

They have a [current density limit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission) which depends on their surface chemistry and temperature.

In related devices (e.g. cathode ray tubes in older TVs, vacuum amplifier tubes, fluorescent tubes, etc) the current is controlled in one way or another and the cathode usually operates well below this limit.

In an x-ray tube, the cathode is operated at its own current limit so the voltage does not affect the current, at least not at voltages that at all produce x-rays.

And then, one can pretty much change the current and the intensity by altering the cathode heating voltage (tube warranty void at this point!).

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer